# Hovering div and image problems with jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm having a conflict with the way I have an .animation going with JQuery.

I have an image that holds showthis() and hidethis() functions:

```
function hidethis() {
    $('#info1').animate({
        bottom: '-150px',
    }, 100);
}
function showthis() {
    $('#info1').animate({
        bottom: '0px',
    }, 500);
}
```

the elements I have are an image placed on the page, and a div position: fixed; over the image as a show/hide information tab.

Here are the styles for each element:

```
.slide img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.info {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -150px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 527px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

And JQuery is triggered by onmouse events within the image: 
`onmouseover="javascript:showthis();" onmouseout="javascript:hidethis();"`

### **The conflict:**

The div that is floating above the image (that shows every time the visitor hovers their mouse over the image) is conflicting with the onmouseout on the image. If you hover over the image, the div shows. But if you hover over the div while still hovering over the image, the div hides and it gets 'confused' and starts going in and out multiple times while I am still moving my mouse above the image where the div is coming up. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You probably want to try using [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events.

Comment: Place both the image and the info element in a containing element, and attach the event handlers to that element, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: as in `onmouseenter="javascript:showthis();" onmouseleave="javascript:hidethis();"` ? If so, I put it in, and for some reason, that just doesn't want to work all together...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the event handler on the image, but on a containing element to avoid issues with the mouse leaving the image and entering the `.info` element, like so:

HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <img src="someimgage.png" />
    <div class="info">Some info</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.slide').on({
    mouseenter: showthis,
    mouseleave: hidethis
});
```

Also, you're using `#info1` in the functions, but `.info` in the CSS, what is it ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MRkhu/1/)

Comment: .info is just the style. I like to keep them seperate. id for jquery and class for style. I will give this a try.

Comment: There's no need to assign ID's just for jQuery, many times classes are a lot more suited.